# Access current tab url in background.js chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

Would like to access the current tab url in `background.js`

Had already used following code in `background.js`

```
 window.chrome.tabs.query({ "active": true, "windowId": window.chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT },
    (tabs) => {
        console.log("Tab Url ", tabs);
        if (Array.isArray(tabs) && tabs.length > 0 && tabs[0]["url"]) {
            console.log("Tab Url ", tabs[0]["url"]);
        }
    }
);

chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(undefined, function (tabs) {
    for (var i = 0, tab; tab = tabs[i]; i++) {
        console.log(tab);
        if (tab.url) {
            console.log(tab.url)
        }
    }
});


chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function (tab) {
    console.log(tab.url);
});

chrome.tabs.query({ 'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true, 'currentWindow': true }, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    console.log(url);
    alert(url)
})
```

With and without parent function

```
window.chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab){...code})
```

**manifest.json**

```
"background": {
  "scripts": [
    "background.js"
  ],
 "persistent": true
},
"permissions": [
  "identity",
  "activeTab",
  "tabs"
],
```

For all the above results, I am receiving `undefined` for the current URL.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you did reload your extension after adding the required `tabs` permission, there are two problems: a) [chrome bug](/a/63886442) when devtools is open for the background script and b) your current background script isn't really usable, you need an API event, [more info](/a/63966400)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing `window.chrome.tab.query` you can just do `chrome.tabs.query`. Also in the updated version of the chrome API, you can get the current tab url by passing `currentWindow` and `active` as `true`.

So, the request to get the current tab becomes :

```js
const currentTab = chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(){});
console.log(currentTab.url);
```